# Accessing the model

Tags: error, model

i've a problem with accessing my model class. 
I just want to access the class Test and execute the function getGnarf but 
everytime i try, i get the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getGnarf() on a non-object".

The Test Class:

```
<?php 
class Tools_Webservice_Model_Test {
    function getGnarf() {
        return "Zoor";
    }
}
?>
```

I don't need to extend the class with the Mage_COre_Model_Abstract because of no DB functionality is needed ?

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Tools_Webservice>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Tools_Webservice>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <modules>
            <webservice>
                <class>Tools_Webservice_Model</class>
            </webservice>
        </modules>
        <helpers>
                <webservice>
                        <class>Tools_Webservice_Helper</class>
                </webservice>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

The calling class:

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

$model = Mage::getModel('webservice/test');              
echo $model->getGnarf();  // leads to fatal error
```

Thx for your help !

Comment: Try adding public to the getGnarf() declaration. Also check if you get an instance of the model inside $model with a var_dump()

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `global` node, you have `modules`, I think you meant `models`. Other than that it looks about right.

Comment: We've all done it I'm sure. I've spent hours debugging typos in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You  have not properly define in module there issue inn

**Issue 1:**

should be   .It magento logic .please check at config.xml

So

```
<model>
            <webservice>
                <class>Tools_Webservice_Model</class>
            </webservice>
        </model>
```

Should be

```
<models>
            <webservice>
                <class>Tools_Webservice_Model</class>
            </webservice>
        </models>
```

If you have define block and helper and model the then you need define  `<blocks>...</blocks>,<helpers>.... </helpers>,<models>..<models>` with proper object type